# loading SQLite data into listview

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, android-layout, listview

I am trying to load my SQLite data into listview. but my application stops when the database retireval activity is called.

This is my Logcat

```
03-02 11:05:04.488: I/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-02 11:05:04.579: I/dalvikvm(24942): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-02 11:05:04.898: I/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-02 11:05:04.918: I/dalvikvm(24942): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-02 11:05:05.118: D/gralloc_goldfish(24942): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-02 11:05:06.978: D/AndroidRuntime(24942): Shutting down VM
03-02 11:05:06.978: W/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.grammer/com.example.grammer.Database}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:267)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:145)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at com.example.grammer.Database.displayListView(Database.java:81)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at com.example.grammer.Database.onCreate(Database.java:38)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-02 11:05:07.048: E/AndroidRuntime(24942):    ... 11 more
03-02 11:05:07.178: I/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-02 11:05:07.199: I/dalvikvm(24942): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-02 11:05:07.678: I/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-02 11:05:07.698: I/dalvikvm(24942): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-02 11:05:08.099: I/dalvikvm(24942): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-02 11:05:08.109: I/dalvikvm(24942): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-02 11:05:09.149: I/Process(24942): Sending signal. PID: 24942 SIG: 9
```

The activity which is called is Database activity.
This is as follows.

```
public class Database extends Activity {


     private DatabaseHandler dbHelper;
     private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exercise);


        dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        displayListView();

    }


    private void displayListView() {

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchQuestions();

        // The desired columns to be bound
          String[] columns = new String[] {
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ROWID,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_TITLE,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER1,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER2,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER3,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER4,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER,
                  DatabaseHandler.KEY_ANSWER_TEXT
              };


        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
          int[] to = new int[] { 
                    R.id.id,
                    R.id.title,
                    R.id.question,
                    R.id.ans1,
                    R.id.ans2,
                    R.id.ans3,
                    R.id.ans4,
                    R.id.ans,
                    R.id.ansnum,
                  };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
          //as well as the layout information
          dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.questions_info, 
            cursor, 
            columns, 
            to,
            0);


          ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          // Assign adapter to ListView
          listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

          listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                 int position, long id) {
               // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
               Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

               // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
               String question = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("code"));
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       question, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
              });


         }
        }
```

My database handler class

```
public class DatabaseHandler{

    // Contacts Table Columns names
     static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
     static final String KEY_NAME = "questions";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "question_title";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER1 = "answer1";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER2 = "answer2";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER3 = "answer3";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER4 = "answer4";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    public static final String KEY_ANSWER_TEXT = "answer_text";

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";
     private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
     private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "grammer";
    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS = "questions";

     private final Context mCtx;

     private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
              "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_QUESTIONS + "("
                        + KEY_ROWID +" integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_ANSWER1 + " TEXT," + KEY_ANSWER2 + " TEXT," + KEY_ANSWER3 + " TEXT," 
                        + KEY_ANSWER4 + " TEXT," + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_ANSWER_TEXT + " TEXT" +")";;



    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
               super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
              }

        @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
           db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
          }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
               Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                 + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTIONS);
               onCreate(db);
              }

    }

    public DatabaseHandler(Context ctx) {
          this.mCtx = ctx;
         }


    public DatabaseHandler open() throws SQLException {
          mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
          mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          return this;
         }


    public void close() {
          if (mDbHelper != null) {
           mDbHelper.close();
          }
         }


    public long addQuestion(String Question, String Answer1, String Answer2, String Answer3, String Answer4, String Answer, String Answer_Text, String Question_Title) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, Question); // question Name
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER1, Answer1); // answer
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER2, Answer2); // answer
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER3, Answer3); // answer
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER4, Answer4); // answer
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER, Answer); // answer
        initialValues.put(KEY_ANSWER_TEXT, Answer_Text);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, Question_Title);

              return mDb.insert(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null, initialValues);
             }


    public boolean deleteAllQuestions() {

          int doneDelete = 0;
          doneDelete = mDb.delete(TABLE_QUESTIONS, null , null);
          Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
          return doneDelete > 0;

         }



     public Cursor fetchQuestions() {


         Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_QUESTIONS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_ANSWER1, KEY_ANSWER2, KEY_ANSWER3, KEY_ANSWER4, KEY_ANSWER, KEY_ANSWER_TEXT, KEY_TITLE }, 
                    null, null, null, null, null);       


          if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
          return mCursor;

         }

}
```

My .xml page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="ID: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Question Title: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Question: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Answer1: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Answer2: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="Answer3: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Answer4: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:text="Answer Number: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="Correct Answer: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextViewid" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextViewtitle" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextViewQuestion" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextViewAns1" />


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ans1"
        android:text="TextViewans2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/question"
        android:text="TextViewAns3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ans3"
        android:text="TextViewAns4" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ansnum"
        android:text="TextViewcorrectans" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ansnum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextViewcorrectansnumber" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can figure out that the code logcat says something about _id which I cannot find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting docs

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not
>   work. Additionally, using MergeCursor with this class will not work if
>   the merged Cursors have overlapping values in their "_id" columns.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Change this

```
static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
```

to

```
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

Comment: It would be better to use BaseColumns._ID rather than define your own version of this constant.

Comment: @Dobbo yes. i guess there is a example of the same with loaders. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html. gotta check the docs

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used SimpleCursorAdapter. for using simple cursor adapter you must have a column  named `_id` in your query. Otherwise SimpleCursorAdapter will not work.

So it is better you use your own CustomCursorAdapter.